# Why do function calls slow things down in clojure?

Tags: performance, clojure

I've been playing around with the [Is Clojure is Still Fast?](http://www.learningclojure.com/2013/02/clojure-is-fast-is-clojure-still-fast.html) (and prequel [Clojure is Fast](http://www.learningclojure.com/2010/09/clojure-is-fast.html)) code. It seemed unfortunate that inlining the differential equation (`f`) is one of the steps taken to improving performance. The cleanest/fastest thing I've been able to come up without doing this is the following:

```
; As in the referenced posts, for giving a rough measure of cycles/iteration (I know this is a very rough
; estimate...)
(def cpuspeed 3.6) ;; My computer runs at 3.6 GHz
(defmacro cyclesperit [expr its]
  `(let [start# (. System (nanoTime))
         ret# ( ~@expr (/ 1.0 ~its) ~its )
         finish# (. System (nanoTime))]
     (println (int (/ (* cpuspeed (- finish# start#)) ~its)))))

;; My solution
(defn f [^double t ^double y] (- t y))
(defn mysolveit [^double t0 ^double y0 ^double h ^long its]
  (if (> its 0)
    (let [t1 (+ t0 h)
          y1 (+ y0 (* h (f t0 y0)))]
      (recur t1 y1 h (dec its)))
    [t0 y0 h its]))
; => 50-55 cycles/it

; The fastest solution presented by the author (John Aspden) is
(defn faster-solveit [^double t0 ^double y0 ^double h ^long its]
  (if (> its 0)
    (let [t1 (+ t0 h)
          y1 (+ y0 (* h (- t0 y0)))]
      (recur t1 y1 h (dec its)))
    [t0 y0 h its]))
; => 25-30 cycles/it
```

The type hinting in my solution helps quite a bit (it's 224 cycles/it without type hinting on either `f` or `solveit`), but it's still nearly 2x slower than the inlined version. Ultimately this performance is still pretty decent, but this hit is unfortunate.

Why is there such a performance hit for this? Is there a way around it? Are there plans to find ways of improvingthis? As pointed out by John in the original post, it seems funny/unfortunate for function calls to be inefficient in a functional language.

Note: I'm running Clojure 1.5 and have `:jvm-opts ^:replace []` in a project.clj file so that I can use lein exec/run without it slowing things down (and it will if you don't do this I discovered...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Benchmarking in the presence of a JIT compiler is tricky; you really must allow for a warm-up period, but then you also can't just run it all in a loop, since it may then be proved a no-op and optimized away. In Clojure, the usual solution is to use Hugo Duncan's [Criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium).

Running a Criterium benchmark for `(solveit 0.0 1.0 (/ 1.0 1000000) 1000000)` for both versions of `solveit` results in pretty much exactly the same timings on my machine (`mysolveit` ~3.44 ms, `faster-solveit` ~3.45 ms). That's in a 64-bit JVM run with `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`, using Criterium 0.4.2 (`criterium.core/bench`). Presumably HotSpot just inlines `f`. In any case, there's no performance hit at all.

Comment: Wow... thank you so much. I had read that performance profiling in clojure was a little tricky cause of the JVM, but I assumed the differences were only minor. I just profiled a function that had around a 20x difference using time versus bench!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the already good answers, the JVM JIT most often does inline the primitive function calls when warmed up, and in this case, when you bench it with a warmed JIT you see the same results. Just wanted to say Clojure also has an inlining feature though for cases where that yields benefits.

```
(defn f
  {:inline-arities #{2}
   :inline (fn [t y] `(- (double ~t) (double ~y)))}
  ^double [^double t ^double y]
  (- t y))
```

Now Clojure will compile away the calls to `f`, inlining the function at compile time. Whereas the JIT will inline the function at runtime as needed otherwise.

Also note that I added a `^double` type hint to the return of `f`, if you don't do that, it gets compiled to return `Object`, and a cast needs to be added, I'm not sure if that really affects performance much, but if you want a fully primitive function that takes primitives and return primitives you need to type hint the return as well.